# Terraform reuse IAM policy statements for different resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a few `aws_iam_policy_document` blocks which share some common statements which grant the same permissions, but for different resources:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_s3_get_put_bucket_one" {
  ...other statements
  
  statement {
    sid    = "example"
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:GetObjectVersion",
      "s3:GetBucketAcl",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation"
    ]
    resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-one"]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_s3_get_put_bucket_two" {
  ...other statements

  statement {
    sid    = "example"
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:GetObjectVersion",
      "s3:GetBucketAcl",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation"
    ]
    resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-two"]
  }
}
```

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to split out the common part of the statements, and simply pass in the resource that the statement should apply to. It seems that I cannot use `source_policy_documents` and `override_policy_documents` here, as that functionality does not allow for partial overriding of statements.

Comment: You can use a `dynamic` block: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.

Comment: Hey @iamanox, you found a way to implement this? I'm in the same boat.